# The input stream is not a valid binary format

Tags: c#, serialization, dotnet-httpclient, webapi, .net-4.8

My class is

```
[Serializable]
public class Class1 : ISerializable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Class1() { }

    Class1(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Id = (int)info.GetValue(nameof(Id), typeof(int));
        Name = (string)info.GetValue(nameof(Name), typeof(string));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(Id), Id);
        info.AddValue(nameof(Name), Name);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}; {Name}";
    }
}
```

My Web API serializes this class then sends as byte array;

```
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    public byte[] Get()
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1()
        {
            Id = 100,
            Name = "Name"
        };
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, class1);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

In my WinForms application I am trying to get this serialized class and resurrect it,

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    Uri uri = new Uri(textBox1.Text);

    var bytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);

    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var class1 = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream) as Class1;
        richTextBox1.Text = class1.ToString();
    }
}
```

But the method `Deserialize` is throwing an exception saying "The input stream is not a valid binary format."

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you use other serializers? `BinaryFormatter` is not recommended for data processing today. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide

Comment: Please do not use `BinaryFormatter`, it is unsafe, slow, brittle, and kills bunnies. There are much better alternatives, for example [protobuf.Net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net), and webAPIs are usually expected to use standard web formats like json, if you want to use binary serialization you should take a look at gRPC. But whatever you do, please think of the bunnies.

Comment: I appreciate your advices, but I don't have a security or performance issues right now. I would like to know the cause of the exception.

Comment: Have you checked the Length of the byte arrays after serialization and before deserialization? Are they the same?

Comment: `OnSending: array.Length=151; OnRecieving: array.Length=206;` This what I don't have a clue about.

Comment: Is the received byte array totally different from the sent one? Or does it have some extra prefix / suffix bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to exchange an object between the server and client. Somehow I did it in a wrong way. First of all, there is no need to serialize the object manually. What we need is to send the object directly, not its serialized bytes. ASP.NET MVC takes care of serialization for us, according to my understanding. So, the API method should be

```
public Class1 Get()
{
    return new Class1()
    {
        Id = 100,
        Name = "Name"
    };
}
```

There is a package called `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` which ads support for formatting and content negotiation to `System.Net.Http`. The assembly called `System.Net.Http.Formatting`, a part of the package, does both serialization and deserialization. When we create a new web application, Visual Studio installs this package automatically into the project.

However, for `Windows Forms` project it must be manually installed via NuGet package manager. The package installation will add 2 assemblies to the project, `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.Net.Http.Formatting`. Then, the rest is very simple

```
private void GetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
    var content = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result.Content;
    var class1 = content.ReadAsAsync<Class1>().Result;
    richTextBox1.Text = class1.ToString();
}
```

And Bob's your uncle!!!

Comment: Please prefer async await over .Result

Comment: Definitely! This is just a test. I am learning :).